# How to find the position of a linked Revit file

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am Writing an app to find the position of the Revit links in the Project. I use the locationPoint but it gives null. T

```
      FilteredElementCollector collector = new   FilteredElementCollector(myDoc);//
                  collector.OfClass(typeof(Instance)).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_RvtLinks);

       foreach (Element elLink in collector)
        {
          Instance ins = elLink as Instance;
          RevitLinkType linkType = myDoc.GetElement(ins.GetTypeId()) as                          RevitLinkType;
                 LocationPoint pn = linkType.Location as LocationPoint;

            TaskDialog.Show("rvt", "Name " + linkType.Name);
            if (null != pn)
            {
                TaskDialog.Show("rvt", "location " + pn.Point.X + "     "         + pn.Point.Y + "    " + pn.Point.Z);
            } 
      }
```

I expect to find the x, y, z of the Revit linked file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) discussion of [Determining Host Document Location of a Linked Element](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/11/determining-host-document-location-of-a-linked-element.html):

> `RevitLinkInstance` is derived from the `Instance` class, the base class for all instance objects. It provides the methods `GetTransform`, to retrieve the transform of the instance, and `GetTotalTransform` that includes the true north transform as well.